# Angular Observable, sharing data within components

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I'm making my first App on Angular. I trying to filter a list of book objects by the gender attribute. I am having difficulty sharing data between components: the `filteredData` variable and the list of books `FireBaseList`.

I am trying to pass the `filteredData` variable from `fixed-nav.component` to `books-grid.component`. From my research, I know I need to make the `books-grid.component` "bookList" observable of any changes and have the `bookList` on `fixed-nav.component.ts` emit an event on any changes on `this.bookList`

However, I am unable to achieve this. I know there are many questions about observables already but none use Firebase. Hope anyone out there can help me, THANKS!!

fixed-nav.component that I use as filter

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BookService } from '../../../services/book.service';
    import { Book } from '../../../models/book';

    @Component({
      selector: 'fixed-nav',
      templateUrl: './fixed-nav.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./fixed-nav.component.css']
    })
    export class FixedNavComponent implements OnInit {

      Genders: string[];
      bookList: Book[];

      constructor(private bookService: BookService) {

        this.Genders = ["Historia","Literatura", "Infantil", "Juvenil","Poesía","Narrativa"];      
      }

      filterByGender(gender: string){

        this.bookService.getBooks() // FIREBASE
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(item => {
          this.bookList = [];
          item.forEach(element => {
            let x = element.payload.toJSON();
            x["$key"] = element.key;
            this.bookList.push(x as Book)
          })
            const filteredData = this.bookList.filter( function(element){
            return element.gender == gender;
            });
            return filteredData; // I WANT TO SHARE THIS DATA
        })
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

books-grid.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BookService } from '../../services/book.service';
import { Book } from '../../models/book';


@Component({
 templateUrl: './books-grid.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./books-grid.component.css']
  })

 export class BooksGridComponent implements OnInit {

  bookList: Book[];

   constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.bookService.getBooks()  // FIREBASE
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(item => {
    this.bookList = [];
      item.forEach(element => {
      let x = element.payload.toJSON();
      x["$key"] = element.key;
      this.bookList.push(x as Book)
        })
               // SHARED DATA HERE
    })
  }
}
```

book.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Book } from '../models/book';  // Model


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BookService {

 bookList: AngularFireList<any>;
 selectedBook: Book = new Book(); // Temporally save selected Book

constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

 getBooks(){
    return this.bookList = this.firebase.list('books');
  }
}
```

books.model.ts

```
    export class Book {
      $key: string;
      title: string;
      author: string;
      gender: string;
      language: string;
      image: string;
      likes: number;
      price: number;
      new: boolean;
    }
```

Comment: Think about moving any filtering code, or shared lists into the `BookService`. That way, you can share the full or filtered list from there. Any component that uses the `BookService` can use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `book.service.ts` create a `filterdData` variable and function to set `filterdData` like below. Import `Subject` using `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';`

```
 filteredData  = new Subject<any>();

  setFilteredData(data) {
    this.filteredData.next(data);
  }
```

And then in your `fixed-nav.component.ts` after done filtration set that filtered data like below

```
 this.bookService.setFilteredData(filteredData);
```

Finally subscribe to the `filteredData` in `book.service.ts` from `books-grid.component.ts` like below and assign the data into variable that you want.

```
 constructor(private bookService: BookService) {
     bookService.filteredData.subscribe((data)=>{
      // Assign the data into variable that you want e.g this.filteredData = data;
    })
 }
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: thanks a lot, this is working! gonna try the option above too, do you think it its better option? so i can use that service in any other component

Comment: @Sergi glad to hear that :) . yes, you could use this service other component as well it will work fine

Comment: hey i have a problem, everytime i subscribe to changes, it stacks,like its subscribing to all events, how to instance Subject<any>()  so it only subscribe once

Comment: implements `OnDestroy` on your component, and inside `ngOnDestroy()` unsubscribe from the observable. e.g. first declare a `subscription: ISubscription;` variable and assign `this.subscription = bookService.filteredData.subscribe((data)=>{ })` and inside `ngOnDestroy()` use like this `this.subscription.unsubscribe();`

Answer (score 2):

you could utilize another shared service, where you update the booklist and then **subscribe** to any change event of this filtered booklist from your **BooksGridComponent** or any other component in need. I edited your code a little bit.

**Something like this:**

Create a new Service, where you return the filtered BooksList as an Observable, so any component can subscribe to it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'; // For rxjs 6

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService {

   private filteredBookList: Subject<Book[]> = new Subject<Book[]>();

   constructor() {}

   public getFilteredBookList(): Observable<Book[]> {
     return this.filteredBookList.asObservable();
   }

   public setFilteredBookList(books: Book[]): void {
     this.filteredBookList.next(books);
   }
}
```

**fixed-nav.component.ts:**

Here you simply call the SharedDataService and set the filteredBookList.

```
this.sharedDataService.setFilteredBookList(filteredData);
```

**And now in your books-grid.component.ts:**

Here you are going to subscribe to any changes of the filteredBookList

```
this.sharedDataService.getFilteredBookList().subscribe((books: Book[]) => {
  // Do Something with the filtered BookList from SharedDataService
})
```

Comment: having some troubles importing 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: It should work fine without that import. I edited the answer!