# Select object in a list from previous component Angular

Tags: angular, list, service, components, highlight

I have a `details.component` and a `list.component`. My App is about cars.

You can open up a car in the `details component` to see it's details. After returning to the `list component` by pressing the back button (integrated back-button), the car you looked before should be selected/highlighted.

The list component is a large list of all cars. I am using bootstrap. I guess the car from the details component must be overhanded with a service? Or is there a simple solution?

I'm a beginner in angular. I would appreciate any kind of examples. Thank you very much

UPDATE:

`list.component`

```
carId$ = this.routerQuery.selectParams<number>('carId').pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    untilDestroyed(this),
    filter(carId => +carId > 0)
  );

constructor(carService){

this.carId$.subscribe(carid => {
              this.carService.getCarById(+carid);
              console.log(carid)
            })
```

How can I highlight / select the last viewed car in the html file?

Comment: yes you should use a service for that kind of action. I wrote an answer about creating a service in general. Set the lastSelectedCar in the service and observe it (subscribe to it) in the list component, then lookup the lastSelected car in ur list and set the selected style. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343636/angular-observable-sharing-data-within-components/51344506#51344506 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355066/how-to-implement-behavior-subject-using-service-in-angular-8/57355485#57355485. Check both posts they should lead u in the right direction. regards

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you provide some example code? I could not figure it out yet

Comment: I will if u provide some information about your component code, for both the list and the detail view

Comment: Each car has an ID. It shows up at the end of the URL. It is the carId (unique). When I open a car on the list component, I get to the detail component. After I press back on my implemented back-button, I get back to the list component. The recently viewed/opened car should be highlighted now. So you have a better overview on which list object you recently viewed.

Comment: My idea is to pass the id from details to the service. The service passes the id to the list component. And in the list component I give the last viewed id a selected/highlighted class

Comment: okay I ll show u a service way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a full example stackblitz for you.

I created two components: `cars.component` and `detail.component`
I created a `car.service.ts` which is handling selection and emulating retrieving cars, probably by a backend.

I am getting the id from the url to retrieve the data by a backend call.

Here is the stackblitz:
[Cars selection service example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-car-selection-service-example)

Comment: did it help mate?

Comment: Yes thanks mate. However I had to edit your solution a little bit. I updated my question. Can you have a look please? Thank you very much

Comment: For me there is no difference. You have a service where you can set the last selected car in my solution. Then u just bind your selected car from the service in the template. regards

Answer (score 0):

For this, You can use anchor tag with **routerLinkActive** and **routerLinkActiveOptions** attribute. Each of your CarList should be wrapped with anchor element. Change the class-name on click on your element.

Something like this,

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="visited" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">Benz</a>
```

Your css code can be something like this,

```
.visited{
    color:red;
}
```

Reference :
[Change color of selected link in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919031/change-color-of-selected-link-in-angular-4)